# Transparent,Unclickable and unfocusable window in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I want a small window to be opaque and cant get focus with any clicks, Like a ghost.
I want that when I click on the java window, nth happens and the bellow window(s) takes the mouse action!
have tried these :

> Frame.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel;

    public Frame() {
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setAutoRequestFocus(false);


        this.setOpacity((float) 0.5);
        this.setFocusable(false);
        this.setFocusableWindowState(false);
        this.setFocusCycleRoot(false);

        panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(37, 72, 107, 102);
        panel.add(tabbedPane);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 20);
        panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

> Main.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
         Frame f = new Frame();
         f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

*my window appears transparent but it listens to my clicks when I click on it and I don't want it!*

Comment: Provide a minimum reproducible example, not just a segment of code.

Comment: @Jason Done bro.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with neither Swing nor javafx. You can make mouse events pass through pixels that are fully transparent and have nothing drawn on them, but that's it. With that said, I found an old piece of software running on java which achieved the effect your asking for. It wasn't open-source unfortunately but at least it shows it's been possible on old versions of Java

Comment: @Dejke hmm. thx mate. So I can't achieve that with java.I must try it on C# it seems.